# A really simple factorization question.

Tags: factoring

Can these equations be factorized?

Expression type: $x^2 + p x + q$

$$ x^2 + 5x - 36\tag{1}$$

$$ x^2 - 7x + 12\tag{2}$$

Comment: A little bit... kinda

Comment: Please don't post images. Type out images and share your work. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: That cubic is actually a pretty famous one...

Comment: I don't know what to do here that's the problem. This looks really simple and it must be for you guys so please tell me how to.

Comment: @Max Oh I'm sorry sir I'll keep those tips in kind.

Comment: just find the root then you have your factorisation.

Comment: @quallenjäger, that is extremely inaccurate.  Questions about factoring quadratics are perfectly welcome here provided the asker follows the guidelines.  Math Overflow is the place where such a question would be not appropriate.

Comment: @tilper I thought we have some homework policy that such level of question will take the teaching effect away and no complete solution can be given. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @quallenjäger, there are no policies that call for a lower limit on the level of question that can be asked here.  Technically there's an upper limit in that research-level questions should be asked on Math Overflow.  Otherwise all levels are welcome here.  The only policy regarding homework is that we aren't supposed to do people's homework for them, regardless of the level.

Comment: It's solved! This is how I did it: x^2 +5x -36; x^2 +9x -4x -36; x(x+9) -4(x+9); (x+9)(x-4)

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help! I will definitely be careful in the future about what questions I ask. Thank you all again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First equation: $q=-36$, $p=5$. The factors of $36$ are
$$(1, 36), (2, 18), (3, 12), \boxed{(4,9)}, (6,6)$$

Which of these pairs has a difference of $5$?

$$x^2 + 5x - 36 = (x-4)(x+9)\tag{1}$$

---

Second equation: $q=12$, $p=7$. The factors of $12$ are
$$(1,12), (2,6), \boxed{(3,4)}$$

Which of these pairs has sum of $7$?

$$x^2 - 7x + 12= (x-3)(x-4)\tag{2}$$

---

You see how the game is played. Create your factors list. Stop just before the first number is bigger than the second. For example, in the second list you would not consider $(9,4)$ because that combination is already listed as $(4,9)$.

Then sweep through the factors and look at sum and difference.